# Pandas Add Column Comparison Result

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

How can I add a comparison column (i.e. for `lead`) to my data frame, for each row in the data frame. It should takes the column mean (overall lead mean) and subtract its monthly mean. Can this be done with an `apply` and lambda using a `groupby`?

I.e. how can I create an additional comparison column, `Lead_Diff`, that is the difference of the row items "monthly avg reading" versus its overall/column mean. Below is a mockup of my data, thanks in advance.

```
info = {'date': ['01-18', '02-18', '03-18', '01-18','02-18','01-18','03-18'], 
        'lead': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6,0.7],
        'copper': [0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, .2, 0.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(info)
```

Comment: Provide expected output for the above data.

Comment: if you want this done for both elements, perhaps you can use something like `df.groupby(df.date.str.split('-').str[0]).transform('mean') - df.mean()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `mean` in new `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame` and subtract `mean` of column:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('date')['lead'].transform('mean') - df['lead'].mean()
print (df)
    date  lead  copper      mean
0  01-18   0.1     0.7 -0.033333
1  02-18   0.2     0.6 -0.050000
2  03-18   0.3     0.5  0.100000
3  01-18   0.4     0.4 -0.033333
4  02-18   0.5     0.3 -0.050000
5  01-18   0.6     0.2 -0.033333
6  03-18   0.7     0.1  0.100000
```

If years are not important and need wotking only with months:

```
#changed data
info = {'date': ['01-18', '03-17', '03-18', '01-18','03-17','01-17','03-17'], 
    'lead': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6,0.7],
    'copper': [0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, .2, 0.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(info)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m-%y')
df['mean'] = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.month)['lead'].transform('mean') - df['lead'].mean()
print (df)
        date  lead  copper      mean
0 2018-01-01   0.1     0.7 -0.033333
1 2017-03-01   0.2     0.6  0.025000
2 2018-03-01   0.3     0.5  0.025000
3 2018-01-01   0.4     0.4 -0.033333
4 2017-03-01   0.5     0.3  0.025000
5 2017-01-01   0.6     0.2 -0.033333
6 2017-03-01   0.7     0.1  0.025000
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution, perfect!